# dynamically added li's, now to dynamically delete them via hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript

Please no jQuery code, as I want to learn javascript first and foremost.

I am just trying something out and I have a button in my html page that dynamically adds `li` items to a `ul`.  Something to this effect:

HTML:

```
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
<input id="myButton" value="Click Me" type="submit" onclick="addItem();"></input>
```

And the JS for `addItem()`:

```
function addItem()
 {
  var l = document.getElementById("myList");  
  var today = new Date();
  var day2 = new Date();
  day2.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);
  var count = 1;

    while(today.valueOf() < day2.valueOf())
           {
            if(today.getDay() == 0)
                 //is it a sunday -- only add sundays...
                {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.setAttribute('id', ['liID' + count]);  //set the id attribute
                    var month = today.getMonth();
                    var day = today.getDate();
                    var year = today.getFullYear();
                    var theDay = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' (Sunday)';
            li.innerHTML = theDay;
            l.appendChild(li);     //add the li to the ul
                }
            today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1) //increment the day
        count++;       
           }
 }
```

This is nice however, next to each line item I would like to also add a hyperlink that would say 'Remove' so that if a user clicks on it, it then would remove that single li.  Do I just do a `document.createElement('a')` ? and set its attribute via `.setAttribute`.  But then how do I trigger the delete for that specific `li`?  Here's my try at it:

### Edit

```
 function addItem()
 {
  var l = document.getElementById("myList");  
  var today = new Date();
  var day2 = new Date();
  day2.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);
  var count = 1;


    while(today.valueOf() < day2.valueOf())
           {
            if(today.getDay() == 0)
                {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.setAttribute('id', ['liID' + count]);
                    var month = today.getMonth();
                    var day = today.getDate();
                    var year = today.getFullYear();
                    var theDay = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ' (Sunday)';
            li.innerHTML = theDay;
            l.appendChild(li);

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.setAttribute('href', '#');
            a.innerHTML = "Remove";
            a.onclick = function(e) {  
                                                var liNode;   
                        if (!e) var e = window.event;   
                        if (e.target) liNode = e.target;   
                        else if (e.srcElement) liNode = e.srcElement;   
                        if (liNode.nodeType == 3) 
                        { // defeat Safari bug        
                          liNode = liNode.parentNode;       
                        }   
                        // l refers to ul which you've an instance of already   
                        l.removeChild(liNode);
                                            }

                    li.appendChild(a);
                }
            today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)
        count++;
           }
 }
```

But when I click the href link it does not remove anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add `a` using `var anchor = document.createElement('a');`. And yes, you can add attribute by using `setAttribute` or just by using `anchor.href = 'http://yourpath.com';`. Then you can add event listener using following code:

```
anchor.onclick = function(e) {
  // crossbrowser event handling
  e = e || window.event;
  var tagret = e.target || e.srcElement;
  // assuming you have appended anchor to li
  var li = tagret.parentNode;
  var ul = li.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(li);
}
```

Comment: @oJM86o, in your updated code it appears that event target is `li`. But it's not. The event target is `a`. Try replace your `onclick` event handler with my. It should work.

Comment: Cool that worked but can you explain it a little, the actual onclick, does e refer to the `a` itself?

Comment: `e.target` refers to element which fired `click` event. In this case this element is `a`. `target.parentNode` refers to element which contain `target` as a child. So in this case `target.parentNode` refers to `li`.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.onclick = function(e) { 
   // cross browser stuff to get the liNode
   var liNode;

   if (!e) var e = window.event;
   if (e.target) liNode = e.target.parentNode;
   else if (e.srcElement) liNode = e.srcElement.parentNode;
   if (liNode.nodeType == 3) { // defeat Safari bug
        liNode = liNode.parentNode.parentNode;
       }
   // l refers to ul which you've an instance of already
   l.removeChild(liNode);
}
li.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, how is the attribute a href added, is it added like I said in my post, and do I set the ID dynamically like I did with the li ?  Then how does e.currentTarget.parent know to go to the `li` from the `a href link`

Comment: Yeah, just like you said. Do a `li.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));` (you can expand it, shown here to give you an idea). Since you're appending the `a` as child, `li` becomes its parent.

Comment: Hey, sorry. When I edited my post for cross broswer stuff, I missed `.parentNode`, this is why it wasn't working for you. Edited it now.